# Error escapes `do-catch` block when calling Firestore API in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Calling `try ... .setData(from: item)` on a document with empty id `.document(item.id)` string crashes the app even if the call is wrapped in a `do-catch` block.

```swift
import FirebaseFirestore
...
        do {
            try db.collection(FBKeys.CollectionPath.users).document(userID).collection(Item.collectionName).document(item.id).setData(from: item)
        } catch {
            Logger.firestore.error("\(error.localizedDescription)") // No executed. The app just crashes.
        }
```

This is a bit unexpected for me. While it is a programmer's mistake to pass an empty document id, the fact that the program crashes in place where it should only throw an error doesn't feel right.
Or is this intended?

Comment: `catch` in Swift doesn't catch _every_ type of error/crash. Just those that are explicitly thrown inside the code.

Comment: What is the message associated with the crash?